# calculation large Adjacency matrix in python with memory

Tags: python-3.x, adjacency-matrix, eigenvector, large-data

I have one adjacency matrix which size is 200,000*200,000, it contains only 0 and 1. it is spares one, because this matrix only has 2,000,000 number of 1.

then, I have difficulty to get it normalized in python on my PC which has 8GB memory.

What I should do to solve it ? the finial goal is to find the eigenvector of this matrix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.